# How is stringWithFormat used here?

Tags: iphone, nsstring

```
NSString *html="html page to parse";
NSString *text="some html text";

html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:
           [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@>", text] withString:@""];
```

My question is what will `@"%@>"` will do in stringwithFormat.

thanks

Comment: [html stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code

```
html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:
           [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@>", text] withString:@""];
```

will replace occurence of **some html text>** in **html page to parse** with empty string.

So the result will be **html page to parse** only.

Using stringWithFormat You can easily perform many operation such as converting an int/float value to string,etc.,

```
int age=18;

NSSring *myage=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"My age is %d", age];
```

Here the value of myage is **My age is 18**.

Comment: that great!. so if I put %@A the above code will replace string upto A with "" isnt?

Answer (score 2):

%@ tells NSString you will be including an object in your string, so it will try to parse it as a string. According to Apple, %@:

"Objective-C object, printed as the string returned by descriptionWithLocale: if available, or description otherwise. Also works with CFTypeRef objects, returning the result of the CFCopyDescription function."

The first @ symbol simply denotes a NSString.

[Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000943)

Comment: Such that the NSString will become **`some html text>`**.